# Is it possible to make a one-off control FET switch circuit?

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay

I was wondering if anyone knew any circuits such that when a small voltage is applied for a short duration (i.e. 500 ms), a switch transitions from the off-state to the on-state or vice versa for all time even after the voltage ceases to be applied. Doing it as follows would not be possible since $$ V_{G1} > V_{TH} + V_{S1}$$
Is required for the NFET to be in forward-active mode, as well as $$ V_{G2} = V_{S1} > V_{S2} + V_{TH}= V_{G1}+ V_{TH}$$

So in fact

$$ V_{TH} <0 $$
Is required for the second switch to constantly keep the first switch in forward active after the signal voltage is applied.

I have tried variations of this with PFETs and combinations, but I keep running into the same problem explained above. I think that it would work with relays since their switching voltages don't depend on the voltage across the relay. But would it work with FETs?

[image]

Comment: I would think whatever solution would necessarily involve a fuse.

Comment: A latching relay springs to mind.

Comment: "even after the voltage ceases to be applied" Do you mean the signal voltage pulse that causes the switching, or the supply voltage of the whole circuit?

Comment: your logic diagram is inverted!

Comment: @RoyC I've reverted your edit; this is in fact meant to be a one-off switch, in that it only switches once and then stays switched.

Comment: Apologies I did not read your question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit you are looking for is called a bistable multivibrator, or flipflop, or latch.  It is a variation of the original multivibrator circuit, which is an oscillator.  You can buy a flipflop as a low-cost integrated circuit in both bipolar and CMOS technologies, or build one with two transistors.

The basic operation is that once the input signal turns on one transistor, the second transistor works to keep the first one turned on after the input signal is removed.

A critical parameter is the amplitude of the input voltage.  Anything over 1 V is easy to deal with.  If you want to stay with MOSFETs, then the input must be greater than 2-3 V for most common devices.  smaller input voltage changes would require an amplifier or comparator stage in front of the latch.

Another part of the design that must be addressed is how to reset the circuit from the latched to unlatched state.  This can be with another signal, a switch, cycling the power to the circuit, etc.

Some of the schematics in this link are of the oscillator circuit, but many are of the latch circuit.

https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrE19zF3ulf0.IAzgFXNyoA;_ylu=Y29sbwNiZjEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZANDMTMzOV8xBHNlYwNwaXZz?p=bistable+flipflop+circuit&fr2=piv-web

Answer (score 3):

If the circuit stays powered, you could use a [(toggle) flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#T_flip-flop) to introduce *state* and drive a MOSFET with it. It will lose its switching state when supply power is removed.

You can roll your own flip-flop using two transistors; information on how to do that is generally available on the interwebs so I won't go there.

If the circuit doesn't stay powered but needs to keep its switching state, a mechanical latching relay comes to mind. It will lock its switching state mechanically and hold it until told to change it. These relays are bulky, though, and not all that common, but available.

If it is just a one-time switch action, a setting that will never be reset but has to remain set when supply power is removed, you could consider blowing a fuse (or not blowing it) and use that as a "switch" that holds state.